# How to display multiple symbols per line in gnuplot legend?

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot I have multiple datasets and wish to display on one line of the legend two different symbols. Here's what I currently have:

[image]

What I would like is to have to the square and the triangle to be on the same line. I am using the epslatex terminal. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it by hand.

The most reliable way is probably to make all the `key` by hand :

Remove all automatic key by issuing `unset key`

Set custom variables to position your key:

```
KEY_X=0.1
KEY_Y=0.9
JUMP=0.05
IDX=1
```

For each `plot` command, issue before it a corresponding `set label` (point styles) or `set arrow` (line styles). E.g.,

```
set label IDX "a" at graph KEY_X,graph KEY_Y+(IDX-1)*JUMP left point pt 7 lc IDX offset 2
replot x with points pt 7 lc IDX
IDX=IDX+1
```

Thus you can add an empty label at the desired position when it comes to have two series with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this might still be of interest. Here are two ugly workarounds:

- reduce the key spacing to `0.5` and plot two `NaN` dummies with `ps 0` and set `title "\n"`.
  The symbols will not be (horizontally) next to each other but at least (vertically) close to each other.
- set `maxrow 3` and `samplen 0` and plot one `NaN` dummy. Although the symbols are (horizontally) next to each other, currently, I don't have an idea how to get them closer to each other.

**Code:**

```
### "one" key entry with two symbols
reset session

set samples 20

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set key top center spacing 0.5
    plot x   w p pt 7 ps 1 lc "red"   title "a", \
         NaN w p      ps 0            title "\n", \
         x*2 w p pt 5 ps 1 lc "blue"  title "b", \
         x*3 w p pt 9 ps 1 lc "black" title "\n", \
         NaN w p      ps 0            title "\n", \
         x*4 w l dt 2 lw 1 lc "black" title "c"
    
    set key top center maxrow 3 spacing 1 samplen 0
    plot x   w p pt 7 ps 1 lc "red"   title "a", \
         x*2 w p pt 5 ps 1 lc "blue"  title "b", \
         x*4 w l dt 2 lw 1 lc "black" title "c", \
         NaN w p      ps 0            title "\n", \
         x*3 w p pt 9 ps 1 lc "black" title "\n"

 unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]